# load properties file from class path

Tags: properties-file

I created a **"AppProp.java"** file to write 3 properties(dabase hostname,dbuser name,dbpassword) in **"config.properties"**.I tried  load properties file from classpath.but it gives error as following ....

```
   **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)
    at App.main(App.java:18)**
```

Now,I want to know ***why*** it ***gives*** ***error***?

Comment: Please provide the code where you write out your properties and also the code where you read them back in again. It looks like the `InputStream` that you are passing to the `load()` method is `null`.

Comment: k..i ll give code.it same copied for http://www.mkyong.com website